# How do I get started with developing in C#?

Tags: c#

The title basically says it all. What programs should I download to start developing in C#? I already have Atom installed it that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Visual studio community/code would be a good start

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visual Studio if a natural choice if you can, because a lot of businesses use that tool for development, and I'm assuming you want to learn it from a career perspective.  However, Microsoft came out with VS Express (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/express/) as a means to get a free version of the tool with limited functionality.  It can work for you and be a good place to start, or look at a tool like VS Code.  That is a nice tool that works a lot differently from Visual Studio, but has a lot of functionality and capabilities.

Sometimes, when you are getting started, you just have to pick an option and go with it; a lot of what you will learn will carry over and there are a lot of good online resources.